# Is the collection of compact subsets of an open and convex set non-empty?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Consider an **open** and **convex** set $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$. Is the collection of **compact** subsets of $B$ non-empty?

Comment: a point is always compact, so you don't even need to assume that $B$ is convex or open or in $\mathbb R^k$. The only thing needed is $B\neq \emptyset$.

Comment: Depending on definition even the empty set is compact ... :D